# How to make pandas .mean(0) .std(0) etc. into a list?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a df and some of the columns contains numbers and I calculate mean, std, median etc on these columns using df.mean(0)..

How can I put these summary statistics in a list?? One list for mean, one for median etc..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use [`Series.tolist`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.tolist.html), because output of your functions is `Series`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],
                   'B':[4,5,6],
                   'C':[7,8,9],
                   'D':[1,3,5],
                   'E':[5,3,6],
                   'F':[7,4,3]})

print (df)
   A  B  C  D  E  F
0  1  4  7  1  5  7
1  2  5  8  3  3  4
2  3  6  9  5  6  3

#sum(0), std(0) is same as sum(), std() because 0 is by default
L1 = df.sum().tolist()
L2 = df.std().tolist()
print (L1)
print (L2)
[6, 15, 24, 9, 14, 14]
[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 1.5275252316519465, 2.0816659994661326]
```

Comment: Glad can help you again! :)